# Login/Register and Currency Widget in Header Wordpress

Tags: php, css, wordpress, header, widget

Woocommerce, Wootique Theme, Currency Widget.

Right what I want to do it to have the currency converter plugin and my Login/Register link in the in the top right corner of the header to the right of my logo like so:

Login/Register |CURRENCY BOX| (On the same row)

The currency converter is a widget and the header was not a widgeted area so i added this bit of code to my functions.php to try to make a widget area:

```html
/*Extra sidebar*/

register_sidebars( 1,
array(
'name' => 'widgetized-page-top',
'before_widget' => '
<div id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
'after_widget' => '</div>
',
'before_title' => '
<h2 class="widgettitle">',
'after_title' => '</h2>
'
)
);
```

Then, I tried to add this code into my header but it hasn't aligned to the right...

```html
<div class="header">

  <div id="topwidget">
    <b><a href="http://casper-creations.com/my-account/" class="footlinks">Login/Register</a>
  
   <?php if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar("widgetized-page-top") ) : ?>
   <?php endif; ?>
 </div>
     
 <div id="logo">
```

I have a feeling this code is completely wrong to begin with, but what I want to do it move it into the header aligned to the right of my logo like I said, like this http://imgur.com/uotLUDd Here is the css I had so far that doesn't seem to be doing much either:

```css
#topwidget {
  float: right;
  width: 980px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Here is the site...

http://www.casper-creations.com

Any help with this would be much appreciated, as I'm sure you can tell I'm just a beginner...

---

EDIT:

I removed the widgeted area thing as just inserted a shortcode instead, but for some reason everything instead in the div isn't working you can't click the links or open the dropdown?

```html
<div id="wrapper">

  <?php if ( function_exists( 'has_nav_menu') && has_nav_menu( 'top-menu' ) ) { ?>

  <div id="top">
    <div class="col-full">

      <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'depth'=>6, 'sort_column' => 'menu_order', 'container' => 'ul', 'menu_id' => 'top-nav', 'menu_class' => 'nav fl', 'theme_location' => 'top-menu' ) ); ?>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- /#top -->

  <div id="logincur">
    <a href="http://casper-creations.com/my-account/"><b>Login/Register</b></a>
    <?php echo do_shortcode( '[woocs]' );?>
  </div>


  <?php } ?>

  <div class="header">
```

```css
#logincur {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 15%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

I have tried putting it into the header div and out of the header div, no change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want #topwidget to float to the right, remove:

```
width: 980px;
```

This makes it span all or most of the screen, so the contents will not be on the right like you want. If you leave the width off, #topwidget will simply have the width of the combined contents.

Comment: That moved it over thanks for that, but now it doesn't do anything?! You can click a link or open the drop down? Also how do I get them on the same line next to each other instead of on separate rows?